# Eliminating openCart Notices and Warning

Tags: php, opencart

I have added the following line in OpenCart front-controller index.php:

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
```

But it still throws undefined-index Notice-Level error. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Login to opencart admin panel
2. Go to `System > Settings`.
3. Click on edit button of your store.
4. In `Server` tab set `No` for the option `Display Errors`.

That's it.

Have a nice day !!